# Use of word "Greetings" instead of morning and evening

Tags: email, greetings

I have a query regarding the use of word only "Greetings" instead of good morning or good evening in the email.

As we will be working in different time zones and we will not be sure when the recipient will check the email.

So what you suggest whether using the word only "greetings" is better instead of using Good morning or Good evening?

Comment: “Greetings” should preferably be followed by “Earthlings” for maximum effect.

Comment: I think "Good day" can be used if you don't know the exact time.

Answer (score 4):

Starting your letter with "Greetings!" is fine. But it sounds a bit stiff in my opinion.

I prefer starting my letters with "Hi X," as I feel it's the appropriate balance between formal and informal. It's delightfully time neutral as well. :D

Try these takes on the same.

http://www.forbes.com/sites/susanadams/2012/08/08/hi-dear-the-state-of-the-e-mail-salutation/

http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2011/jan/09/etiquette-letter-writing-dear-sir

Comment: "Greetings!" sounds archaic or tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: "Hi" is typically considered informal. "Hello" would be the formal variant.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just begin with the person's name. Example:

Jill,

I noticed that you were snacking on the monkey brain sandwich last Tuesday during our Skype session. We have a policy that prohibits snacking on monkey brains during extreme coding marathons. I trust you will adhere to our eating policy in the future.

Best,
Michael Grevious